# Jenkins never gets past triggering configuration

Tags: build, jenkins

I am trying to run an existing jenkins job, however it never gets past the "Triggering Config" section of the console log.  The config however has no settings regarding configurations that I can see, but perhaps I am missing something.  Can anyone help me out?

```
Started by user llaskin
Building remotely on Jenkins Slave 1 in workspace C:\jenkins_slave_leo\workspace\JOBNAME
Triggering <configuration name>
...
```

ETA: I've tried removing the configurtation setups and the Axis' but nothing seems to alleviate this. I'm really unsure where to go from here.

EDIT - From the comment:

This is a matrix job, but there are no settings in the matrix
(hence why configuration name is usually default, I bet).
Build steps are:

1. Copy Artifcats from Another project
2. Execute Windows batch command
3. Invoke Ant

Comment: Please give more details, like: is this a matrix job by any chance? Have you set any build step in this job? Does the job you are trying to trigger even exists?

Comment: This is a matrix job, but there are no settings in the matrix(hence why configuration name is usually default, I bet).  Build steps are: Copy Artifcats from Another project, Execute Windows batch command, Invoke Ant.  I don't know what you mean by does the job exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Matrix-Job in Jenkins has to have at least one axis -
otherwise nothing will be executed except for the
"Manager Job", which is the short log you currently see.

Suggest you add an axis, try to run a basic command (like: `echo testing...`)
and see what you get in each of the sub-jobs.